# Why does StackExchange use Markdown, and not a pure wysiwyg?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, markdown

Is the markdown actually not a technical detail that you don't want to bother your users with?

Of course the buttons are there on top, but you always have to take a look at the bottom of the page how the end results. On top of that you have stuff like the double-space for a return that is really user unfriendly.

I guess everyone would shiver by the idea of writing Word documents like this, so why writing your q/a questions and answers like this?

This is absolutely not meant as a rant, just wondering because we're at the point of implementing a wysiwyg solution for our platform.

I first wrote this question at [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/73079/why-does-stackexchange-use-markdown-and-not-a-pure-wysiwyg), but someone told that meta would be a more appropriate place for this question.

Comment: Short answer: Because many a user would shiver at having to write posts (or texts in general) as if they were Word documents.